# Excel VBA Form control: Opening/creating an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'd to create check if a file is exists using the shipNo and FilePath. If not, copy master.xls and rename the file according to shipNo. In all cases open the file afterwards.

```vb
Private Sub PDFButton_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim SourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension, shipNo As String

    'Initialize variables
    shipNo = Range("D4").Value
    FilePath = "C:\Users\*\Documents\QueueRecord\"
    SourceFile = "C:\Users\*\Documents\QueueRecord\Gen master.xls\"

    If (destFile) = "" Then
        Dim fso, createText As FileSystemObject

        Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, FilePath & "SampleFileCopy.xls\"
        Set createText = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath, True, True)
        createText.Write "success"
        createText.Close

        If fso.FileExists(FilePath & "SampleFileCopy.xls\") Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        End If
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("C:\Users\*\Documents\QueueRecord\" + shipNo + ".xls\")
End Sub
```

In my tests SampleFileCopy.xls is never created, nor is the textFile created.

Comment: when is `destFile` first set?

Comment: Dim fso, createText As FileSystemObject
This creates fso as a variant and createtext as a FileSystemObject, But then you try and set createtext to a textstream

Comment: First commandment: **You shall not use `On Error Resume Next`.** Delete it from your code and you will get a runtime error. Try to understand this error and fix your code

Answer (score 0):

destFile will always be empty the way you have it written. I'm assuming you want the line to look like:

```
If dir(FilePath & shipNo & ".xls") = "" Then
```

Also, remove all the back slashes after the full file paths.

this:

```
"C:\Users\*\Documents\QueueRecord\Gen master.xls\"
```

should be this:

```
Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\QueueRecord\Gen master.xls"
```

Also, as stated in the comments, remove the "on error resume next" so you know where the code is breaking.

Full code below, based on the assumption that destFile is supposed to be filepath and shipNo:

```
Private Sub PDFButton_Click()
    Dim SourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension, shipNo As String

    'Initialize variables
    shipNo = Range("D4").Value
    FilePath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\QueueRecord\"
    SourceFile = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\QueueRecord\Gen master.xls"

    If Dir(FilePath & shipNo & ".xls", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject

        Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, FilePath & "SampleFileCopy.xls"

        'create text file
        TextFile = FreeFile
        Open FilePath & shipNo & ".txt" For Output As TextFile
        Print #TextFile, "success";
        Close TextFile

        If fso.FileExists(FilePath & "SampleFileCopy.xls") Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        End If
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\QueueRecord\" & shipNo & ".xls")
End Sub
```